# Error: <rect> attribute width: Expected length, "NaN". Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I've been fiddling with this for a few days now and I either get the error in the title, or I get "key.call is not a function", and I don't know why... basically the point of the script is to load different csv files based on the selection made in the dropdown.  Without all the dropdown stuff, the script works fine, but once I introduce the dropdown script it starts bugging out and I can't figure out why.  Below is the script, and I'll attach a sample of the kind of csv I'm working with if that helps at all.

Thanks a ton in advance!

CSV example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/24zopp43r3y1ft6/PCC-edit.csv?dl=0 (QC = QuantityCharged in this example)

```
<svg class="chart"></svg>
<select onchange="loadData()" id="metric">
    <option>A-codes</option>
    <option>Anesthesia</option>
    <option>C-codes</option>
    <option>Clinical Components (NRV)</option>
    <option>E-Codes</option>
    <option>Emerging Technology</option>
    <option>Evaluation & Management</option>
    <option>G-codes</option>
    <option>J-codes</option>
    <option>L-codes</option>
    <option>Medicine</option>
    <option>Pathology & Laboratory</option>
    <option>P-codes</option>
    <option>Q-codes</option>
    <option>Radiology</option>
    <option>Surgery</option>
    <option>V-codes</option>
</select>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>



var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top:10, right: 720, bottom: 5, left: 720},
    width = +svg.attr("width") + margin.left + margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") + margin.top + margin.bottom;

var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([3, width]);

var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range([height, 1]);

var chart = d3.select(".chart")
    .attr("width", width);

var parseRow = function(row) {
    return {
        subcategory: row.Subcategory,
        quantityCharged: parseFloat(row.QuantityCharged)
    }
};

//d3
var loadData = function(data) {
    var metric = document.getElementById('metric').selectedOptions[0].text;
    var dataFile = 'data/' + metric + '.csv'
d3.csv(dataFile, parseRow, function(error, data) {
    x.domain([1, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.QuantityCharged; })]);
    y.domain([1, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Charge; })])
});


    chart.attr("height", height);



    var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
        .data("width", data)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * height + ")"; });



    bar.append("rect")
        .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.QuantityCharged); })
        .attr("height", height - 1);

    bar.append("text")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.QuantityCharged) + 10; })
        .attr("y", height / 2)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function(d) { return d.QuantityCharged + " -- " + d.Charge; });

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .ticks(20)
        .orient("top")

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .ticks(24)
        .orient("left");

    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.QuantityCharged); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.QuantityCharged); });

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("data", line);



function type(d) {
    d.QuantityCharged = +d.QuantityCharged; // coerce to number
    d.Subcategory = d.Subcategory;
    return d;
}};


function Subcategory(csv) {
    d3.text(dataFile, parseRow, function(text) {
    var Subcategory = d3.csv.parseRows(text),
    Charge = d3.csv.parseRows(text);

        })}

loadData();

</script>
```